# Why doesn't this "is not" if statement work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code,

```
if diff != "1" or diff != "2" or diff != "3":
            print("You need to pick either 1, 2 or 3\n")
```

For some reason, the outcome is,

```
Pick a difficulty:
1) Easy
2) Medium
3) Hard
>> 2
You need to pick either 1, 2 or 3
```

I want the if statement to check if the variable *diff* **is not** equal to strings *1, 2 and 3*. But when I put either *1, 2 or 3*, the error message for when diff doesn't equal the numbers prints instead. Why does this happen?

Comment: `diff` would have to be equal to all three of `"1"`, `"2"`, and `"3"` to pass that check.

Comment: Use proper parentheses `()` around `or` statement, `if (diff != "1") or (diff != "2") or (diff != "3"):` and try

Comment: @user2357112, no it does not, its an `OR` statement not an `AND`

Comment: @Stack: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: @user2357112, but python just checks the first condition , if it evaluates to True, its skips the rest or else checks the rest

Comment: user2357112 is right. `diff` will always be not equal to at least two of "1", "2", and "3". Use `and` here.

Comment: Why do you use **or** when you say **and**?  Try this: `if diff != "1" and diff != "2" and diff != "3":`

Comment: valid_choices = ['1', '2', '3']; if diff not in valid_choices: print ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply the logic of "not any" you would want to check if it is any of the valid results then invert. (NOR)

```
if not (diff == "1" or diff == "2" or diff == "3"):
```

Or applying [DeMorgan's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) this would be equivelent to "not equal to 1 AND not equal to 2 AND not equal to 3"

```
if diff != "1" and diff != "2" and diff != "3":
```

of course python also has the `in` and `not in` operator which makes this much cleaner:

```
if diff not in ("1", "2", "3"):
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use and instead of or.  If you input 1, then `diff != "1"` returns True.

Your code should look like this:

```
if diff != "1" and diff != "2" and diff != "3":
            print("You need to pick either 1, 2 or 3\n")
```

Comment: "If you input 1, then `diff != "1"` returns True" - no, `diff != "2"` returns True.

Comment: Actually, if you input 1, than `diff != 1` returns False and the other two statements return True, but because I'm using `and`, the if statement as a whole will return False.